# ESLint Javascript:Trying to turn off quotes rule but off seems to be ignored

Tags: javascript, eslint

I am setting up ES Lint and I am trying to disable "strings must have double quotes rule"
I have tried:

```
"quotes":0
"quotes":[0]
"quotes":["off"]
"quotes":["off","double"]
```

None of those seem to be honored and I still get the error. 
However if I put invalid value in the first array position I do get an error saying in is an invalid value so the config file is getting read:
Example:

```
"quotes":["warning"]
```

Comment: Are you sure your config is being read by the ESLint instance correctly? `"quotes": 0` is fine

Comment: Yes because when I put an invalid value in it throws an error